# Implement CVAE for a single image

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, unsupervised-learning, dimensionality-reduction

I have a multi-dimensional, `hyper-spectral` image (`channels, width, height = 15, 2500, 2500`). I want to compress its 15 channel dimensions into 5 channels.So, the output would be (`channels, width, height = 5, 2500, 2500`). One simple way to do is to apply PCA. However, performance is not so good. Thus, I want to use Variational AutoEncoder(VAE).
When I saw the available solution in Tensorflow or keras library, it shows an example of clustering the `whole images` using Convolutional Variational AutoEncoder(CVAE).

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/cvae

https://keras.io/examples/generative/vae/

However, I have a single image. What is the best practice to implement CVAE? Is it by generating sample images by moving window approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing it would be to have a CVAE that takes as input (and output) values of all the spectral features for each of the spatial coordinates (the stacks circled in red in the picture). So, in the case of your image, you would have 2500*2500 = 6250000 input data samples, which are all vectors of length 15. And then the dimension of the middle layer would be a vector of length 5. And, instead of 2D convolutions that are normally used along the spatial domain of images, in this case it would make sense to use 1D convolution over the spectral domain (since the values of neighbouring wavelengths are also correlated). But I think using only fully-connected layers would also make sense.

[image]

As a disclaimer, I haven’t seen CVAEs used in this way before, but like this, you would also get many data samples, which is needed in order for the learning generalise well.

Another option would be indeed what you suggested -- to just generate the samples (patches) using a moving window (maybe with a stride that is the half size of the patch). Even though you wouldn't necessarily get enough data samples for the CVAE to generalise really well on *all* HSI images, I guess it doesn't matter (if it overfits), since you want to use it on that same image.